# 100Mbps internet line go down to 10Mbps on second router

Tags: networking, internet

I have 100Mbps internet speed subscription. I use 2 routers. 1 on ground floor and another on first floor. I want to separate the network of First floor and ground floor that is why I use second router instead of just a switch.

Router1 WAN port is connected to the main ISP box. Router2 WAN port is connected to LAN port of ROUTER 1.

When I connect to wifi/LAN on Router1, I get 100Mbps speed. When I connect to wifi/LAN on Router2 I only get 10Mbps.

ROUTER1 is Linksys EA6350

ROUTER2 is Linksys EA7500

What could possible be wrong here? I did not make any limitation settings. all are in default mode.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the models of routers you are using?  What happens if you switch models or connect via wire to router 2?   Have you done any other troubleshooting?

Comment: What I did so far is to reset both router. After reset. problem persist. Router 2 is EA7500 Linksys. ISP provided router is also linksys but I am not sure about the model. Will check later when I get home.

Comment: What network speed do you get when connected to one of the LAN ports? It can be many problems, and connecting to WIFI is really a bad way to troubleshoot a problem. If only wifi is the problem, then the answer is in its configuration, but if not, then start troubleshooting LAN speeds.

Comment: On router 1 I get the expected speed. 100Mbps. On Router 2 I only get 10Mbps. This happen on both Wifi and/or LAN

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit on this problem.

For some reason, *Media prioritization* is ON on one of the routers, and should be OFF to get the full speed.

Now I get 100 Mbps internet on both routers.